# Joint Pdf Of (min(x1,x2),min(x2,x3))

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

hello everyone i need help to find the JPDF of (min(x1,x2),min(x2,x3)) where x_{1},x2,x3 are independent weibull distribution.

my attempt
P(min(x1,x2)≤y1 , min(x2,x3)≤y2 , x1<x2) =P(x2≤y1 ,min(x2,x3)≤y2 , x1<x2)+P(x1≤y1 ,min(x2,x3)≤y2 , x1<x2)
since x1, x2 and x3 are independent P(x1≤y1 ,min(x2,x3)≤y2 , x1<x2)=P(x1≤y1) P(min(x2,x3)≤y2 , x1<x2))

my problem is how to find P(x2≤y1 ,min(x2,x3)≤y2 , x1<x2)?

Comment: When both  $X_2 < X_1$ and $X_2<X_3$ (a sixth of the time if they are iid) then there is no joint density